# how to exit a loop to another loop?

Tags: vb.net

Anyone know why I can not get a new word when the "for" loop reaches the limit?
 
the intention is that the loop rotate every new word
 
but something very wrong'm doing
================================

```
Private Sub getWord()
        Static wordCount As Integer
        Dim txtLines As String()
        txtLines = TextBox1.Text.Split(CChar(vbCrLf))

        If (wordCount < txtLines.Count) Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.bing.com/search?q=" & txtLines(wordCount) & "&first=1&FORM=PERE")
            wordCount = wordCount + 1
        End If

    End Sub

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim max As Integer = 40

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        If i >= max Then
            getWord()
        End If

        If (WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Then

            For i As Integer = 1 To 40 Step 10
                WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.bing.com/search?q=" & txtLines(wordCount) & "&first=" & i & "&FORM=PERE")
            Next

            Dim PageElement As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
            Dim lk As String
            For Each lks As HtmlElement In PageElement
                lk = lks.GetAttribute("href")
                ListBox1.Items.Add(lk)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question, but I'll take a stab at it.

If you're not getting the expect values from the loop could it be that when you use `For i As Integer = 1 To 40 Step 10` that you only get 1, 11, 21, 31, but that you're expecting five values? Perhaps you need to do this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 41 Step 10
```

Comment: the question is: 
when the loop reaches 40 or 41, a new word should be launched 
why is this not happening?

Comment: @user3606056 - Your current code never reaches 40 or 41. It stops at 31. Your `For` loop only produces the values 1, 11, 21, & 31.